# jQuery `replaceWith();` Can we replace a div (not load into) with php from external file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, replacewith

Can I replace a `<div>` with external php script. Something like this:

`$('#aside').replaceWith('blocks/filename.php');`

Please be gentle I have just started to learn JavaScript.

UPDATE:

I want to replace that `<div id="aside">`. I want to remove it completely and place the new content there.

Comment: no, you cannot do that for obvious reasons. What you can do, is to make an ajax call to that php page, and based on the response, replace `#aside` div.

Comment: Not like that, no, but have a look at the [`.load` ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Use either `.load()` to fetch the contents and load them directly into a holder element, or use `.ajax()` (or `.get()`, which really is just a shorthand) to fetch the content, then manually put it inside the holder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this - *if you want to `replace` `#aside` with new content*

```
$.get("blocks/filename.php", function(data) {
    $('#aside').replaceWith($(data));
});
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. I want to replace that `<div id="aside">`. I want to remove and place the new content.

Answer (score 4):

Not that simply, you can load your PHP into said div tho with a simple `.load` call:

```
$("#aside").load("blocks/filename.php", function() {
    console.log("I've been loaded!");
})
```

API Ref: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Per the edits, you'll want to use a `$.get` function with a callback to replace that div with the new content.

Comment: I do not want to load into that `<div id="aside">`. I want to replace the div completely with the new content.

Comment: I believe `wrap` thrown into the middle of the first line might help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to load the contents from a PHP-file, and put it inside a `<div>` right?
The very easy way would be to send a AJAX GET-request to the file, and fill the contents as such:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'blocks/filename.php', 
  data: {}, 
  success: function(data) {
    $('#aside').replaceWith(data);
  }), 
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

**EDIT:** Changed to replaceWith() instead, as suggested.

Comment: As I was typing, one other just suggested it, didn't want to copy his magnificent work of code :-)

Comment: @MagnusBurton: Because it's more descrptive and shows what happens really - relevant for a JS newbie. Also `$.ajax` has more options, and you can really call `replaceWith()` instead of `html()`

Comment: @Bergi Sure but he wanted just such a simple thing as replacing current data in div to the data from the php file. Load does exactly what he wanted (so does the others, ofc). But why use a chainsaw if you're gonna cut up some salad? Use a knfie for that and the chainsaw for what it's meant for.